# How to map key name to value type of typescript object

Tags: typescript

I have the following :

```
type MSH = {
  val1: string
}

type EVN = {
  val2: string
}

type PID = {
  val3: string
}
type Segment = MSH | EVN | PID

type Segments = {
  MSH: MSH
  EVN: EVN
  PID: PID
}
```

Is there a method to avoid repeating key-type mapping in `Segments`?

Thanks !

Comment: Not really. Identifiers and keys are different, so you'd have to repeat it at least once to associate the string key to the type. You could of course inline the type definition into `Segments`, but that removes the ability to have a named type for each value.

Comment: The only redundancy you could eliminate is to change `Segment`'s definition to `type Segment = Segments[keyof Segments]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for me was to define an interface grouping the type by key/type
then a generic to choose each keys. It's look like Typescript Pick.

```
interface Segments {
  MSH: MSH,
  ENV: EVN,
  PID: PID,
}

type Message<K extends keyof Segments> = {
  [P in K]: Segments[P]
}

type ADT = Message<'MSH' | 'PID'>

const message: ADT
message.MSH //OK
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following

```
type Segments = {
  MSH: {val1:string}
  EVN: {val2:string}
  PID: {val3: string}
}

type Segment = Segments[keyof Segments]
```

Then when you want to use MSH, ENV or PID individually for types you can just use

```
Segments['MSH']
Segments['EVN']
Segments['PID']
```

Rather than redefining the types `MSH`, `EVN` and `PID` explicitly.

Comment: I think this is the best way to do it, maybe not the clearest but thanks